# How to send post value to scroll.php using this javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How to send post value to scroll.php using this javascript ?

i want to send value `$_POST[number] = "12345";` AND `$_POST[user] = "guest";` to scroll.php

how can i do that ?

.....................................................................................................................................................................

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var ajax_arry=[];
 var ajax_index =0;
 var sctp = 100;
 $(function(){
   $('#loading').show();
 $.ajax({
         url:"scroll.php",
                  type:"POST",
                  data:"actionfunction=showData&page=1",
        cache: false,
        success: function(response){
           $('#loading').hide();
          $('#demoajax').html(response);

        }

       });
    $(window).scroll(function(){

       var height = $('#demoajax').height();
       var scroll_top = $(this).scrollTop();
       if(ajax_arry.length>0){
       $('#loading').hide();
       for(var i=0;i<ajax_arry.length;i++){
         ajax_arry[i].abort();
       }
    }
       var page = $('#demoajax').find('.nextpage').val();
       var isload = $('#demoajax').find('.isload').val();

         if ((($(window).scrollTop()+document.body.clientHeight)==$(window).height()) && isload=='true'){
           $('#loading').show();
       var ajaxreq = $.ajax({
         url:"scroll.php",
                  type:"POST",
                  data:"actionfunction=showData&page="+page,
        cache: false,
        success: function(response){
           $('#demoajax').find('.nextpage').remove();
           $('#demoajax').find('.isload').remove();
           $('#loading').hide();

          $('#demoajax').append(response);

        }

       });
       ajax_arry[ajax_index++]= ajaxreq;

       }
    return false;

 if($(window).scrollTop() == $(window).height()) {
       alert("bottom!");
   }
    });

});   
</script>
```

Comment: you need to pass data as a plain object i.e. in {} etc.

Comment: I am little unsure what your asking.  Your already doing an AJAX POST call to scroll.php and sending `actionfunction=showData&page=1`.  So why can't you do `actionfunction=showData&page=1&number=12345&user=guest`?

Comment: append the post values also to that data string.

Comment: i dont see any 'number' or 'user' variables in your JS code

Comment: yse, i want to add more

Answer (score 0):

I would modify your data in the ajax to look something like this.

```
 data: {
     actionfunction : "showData",
     page : 1,
     number: 12345,
     user: "guest"
 },
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `$.ajax()` data could be passed as a **PlainObject**:

```
data: {
    number: "12345",
    user: "guest",
    actionfunction: "showData",
    page: "1"
},
```

I find it easier to read like this.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the variables and values to parameter data of ajax calls

```
$.ajax({
         url:"scroll.php",
                  type:"POST",
                  data:"actionfunction=showData&page=1&number=12345&user=guest",
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be for `type: "GET"` and be a part of the url?

Comment: @adey_888 nope, post are still sent as query strings, they are just not appended on the url, if you want some clarification, try some code and send a jquery ajax, to see a little bit inside the hood, check the network tab, you'll see the form data as a query string, and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29) is a quick read

Comment: Yep, my bad. Just checked the documentation: _data Type: PlainObject or String or Array_ I always use the PlainObject as that's what I prefer because I find it easier to read if there are multiple variables.

Comment: I prefer to use the query string that I can serialize and send an entire form with many data fields